# How can I accurately compute the phase lag variation over time for two time series?

Tags: python

My data set consists of two time series with 1 sample per minute's sampling frequency. When, I plot and see the data, it is very obvious that two time series have a phase lag. However, I am not sure how I can correctly measure the phase lag on temporal basis. Because, I am interested to measure the phase lag change with time.

Here is my script with steps, I used so far for my computation:

**How data looks like**

[image]

**Cross-correlation to measure the phase lag**

**First Attempt**

I directly cross correlate the two time series

```
 d['h_ven']=series1
 d['h_tid']=series2
 corr = signal.correlate(d['h_ven'], d['h_tid'])
 lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(d['h_tid']), len(d['h_ven']))
 corr /= np.max(corr)
 ax1.plot(lags, corr)
```

**Second approach**

I attempted to interpolate first by polynomial fitting:

```
    #inte = d['h_ven'].interpolate(method='spline', order=5)
    #df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=d['h_ven']))
    #x_f = df[["x"]].apply(savgol_filter,  window_length=31, polyorder=2)

   # other approach
 
    res1 = savgol_filter(d['h_ven'], 31, 3)
    res2 = savgol_filter(d['h_tid'], 31, 3)
```

Afterward, I'm sampling again cross-correlate using the same script.

However, I am not sure about the result of cross-correlation.

[image]

May someone suggest me how can, I improve/correct it further.

**Expected Result:**
I expect to the phase delay (in degree/radian within -360 to 360 or -2pi to +2pi) as a function of time. Expected output is attached here:

[image]

Comment: Hey ! Do you have some data samples to share to reproduce ?

Comment: Sure, let me add the data

Comment: I think there is a little problem in your edit (I don't know how you ere planning to give them but could you give them direclty in an array form ?)

Comment: Dear Adnan, this question has already been answered elsewhere. Please check this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541277/how-can-i-get-the-phase-difference-between-two-frequencies.

Comment: Still complementing my prévios comment, the correlation in your problem may cause misleading results. In your case, you are searching for the highest cross-variance, since a cross-correlation has two maximums: one at exactly the same phase, and another exactly at the phase that is equal to half your lambda. In your example, we are seeing the second condition there: an inverted pulse.

Comment: @PhilipeRiskallaLeal Thanks for suggesting useful links, I check with those links, but the point is I need to compute the phase change variation on temporal basis which i unable to compute for your suggested links so far. Indeed, that approach is good, but when your time series are more are less same/smooth. In my case, one time series i very bumpy, while is other series is smooth, so maybe I need to first smooth one series and then go for cross-correlation or any other method for phase calculation. Still looking for meaningful approach.

Comment: Dear Adnan, one other subject worth mentioning is your timeseries size. It's size does indeed impact in the performance of the correlation analysis. The longer the series, the better.

Comment: Dear @PhilipeRiskallaLeal My time series consists of, 14400 (10 days data) data points with sampling frequency of 1 sample per minute. I can extend the duration, but the key point is the accurate measurement of phase change in time.  At present, I am only interested to see the phase change in 10 days window or even shorter.

Comment: @PlainRavioli, I edit my question to improve the clarity, you can have a look now.